# How can I hide the file path in PHP / Xdebug "var_dump()"

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm with Xdebug.

When I use something like `var_dump` how can I hide this part shown in the browser?

[image]

Comment: include code in post, not in a screenshot

Comment: I'm curious _why_ you want this.

Comment: Why does that even matter? Don't you have better things to worry about? Such as, "how do I use a debugger"?

Comment: you are right  .. but just wondering about it .. because i didn't see it in some tutorials

Comment: Look at https://xdebug.org/docs/display >> `overload_var_dump`. Apparently, when that flag is set to `2`, then it appends file name and line number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The `var_dump()` function is used for inspecting and debugging the behavior of your code.** What you're seeing is the Xdebug's version of it *(you have Xdebug enabled and it overloads the default one), which prints out its location, too.*

During the development it is quite helpful to see **when and where exactly** does the `var_dump()` function act out.

If you're worried that it's a security hole, *unless you use `var_dump()` in production,* it most probably is not, since **it's only meant for the developer**. If your users were to see this *(eg. when you forget some `var_dump()` in production code)*, then that would be bad.

---

If you're aware of this and you're still asking **how to "hide the path"**, you might probably want to **disable the Xdebug's version of `var_dump()`**. You can do that with this setting in your `php.ini`:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 0
```

Or really only [hide the path](https://xdebug.org/docs/display#overload_var_dump) with:

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
```

Comment: it worked when i set  ..   xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1 .. thank you

Comment: In xdebug v3 the setting `xdebug.overload_var_dump` is no longer supported.
You can still overload `var_dump()` with `xdebug_var_dump()` using `xdebug.mode=develop`. However, I see no way to use `xdebug_var_dump()` and not show the path anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On Xdebug 3 I haven't found an official way to do it, but I've managed to hide the file name using the settings:

```
xdebug.filename_format = " "
```

(Note that the setting value is a white space and not an empty string)

p.s. If you rely on xdebug error handler, with this settings you might not see files names in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In Xdebug3 you need to turn correct [debug mode](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode)

So, for example `xdebug.mode=off` will turn off `file:line` printing.

Answer (score 0):

If someone are, after today, searching for a solution like me, I have solved this changing the Xdebug.mode to OFF in PHP settings.